# Como verificar em um TXT se alguma coisa se repete?

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo TXT armazenando dados separados por | e gostaria que o php verificase se tem alguma coisa ali se repetindo como faço?

No TXT os dados estão assim:

```
ID|NOME|TELEFONE|ENDERECO|REFERENCIA
```

Todo cliente adicionado salva uma linha dessa. Eu gostaria de verificar se algum telefone está se repetindo. Só o telefone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Um exemplo simples e minimo:

Arquivo de Texto

```
ID|NOME|TELEFONE0|ENDERECO|REFERENCIA
ID|NOME|TELEFONE1|ENDERECO|REFERENCIA
ID|NOME|TELEFONE2|ENDERECO|REFERENCIA
ID|NOME|TELEFONE0|ENDERECO|REFERENCIA
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php

    $item = file("arquivo.txt");

    $items = array_map(function($line)
    {
        return explode("|", $line);
    }, $item);

    $repeat = array();

    foreach($items as $it)
    {       
        $repeat[$it[2]] = 
            isset($repeat[$it[2]])  
            ? (++$repeat[$it[2]])
            : 1;    
    }

    $select = array_filter($repeat, function($item){
        return $item > 1;
    });

    foreach($select as $s) echo $s;
```

Saída:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja ele contabiliza os telefones que se repetem e te mostra quais estão repetidos, é uma maneira muito simples, que até pode sofrer alterações, mas, o intuito é mostrar alguma lógica que possa adequado ao seu código final.

[*Exemplo IDEONE*](https://ideone.com/qDqD0o)

Pode ser criado uma função para ter um código simples de tudo isso, exemplo:

```
<?php

    $item = file("arquivo.txt");

    function item_telefone_repetido($item)
    {
        $items = array_map(function($line)
        {
            return explode("|", $line);
        }, $item);

        $repeat = array();

        foreach($items as $it)
        {       
            $repeat[$it[2]] = 
                isset($repeat[$it[2]])  
                ? (++$repeat[$it[2]])
                : 1;    
        }

        $select = array_filter($repeat, function($item){
            return $item > 1;
        });
        return $select;
    }   


    echo '<pre>';   
    print_r(item_telefone_repetido($item));
    echo '<pre>';
```

ou seja, agora é só chamar a função `item_telefone_repetido` e passar o `array` de valores.